# Adding condition to relationship in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, relationship-class, data-model

I have the following data model:

[image]

Each point and each line can be linked to many measurements (1-M relationship)

I would like to add a condition in the relationship between `MY_LINE` and `MEASUREMENTS`, the relationship should only be active if `A_BOOLEAN` is `TRUE`

Is the best way to do that:

1. Add a new ID to `MY_LINE` and `MEASUREMENTS` which concatenate the fields `THE_ID` and `A_BOOLEAN` and then rebuild the relationship on this new ID;
2. Add a condition in the relationship somehow; or
3. something else?

Comment: Delete all records with False. Why do you mention point here?

Comment: The feature class `MY_POINT` is linked to `MEASUREMENTS` even if `A_BOOLEAN` is False, that is why I can't just delete all records with False !

Comment: Create new field in measurement and populate with ID if True.

Comment: Ok, that was my first solution, but I was curious to know if ArcGIS was able to manage this situation without creating a new ID. If you post an answer with something like, no it's not possible to add a condition to a relationship use a new ID instead I will accept this answer.